Laravel has many through latest model
I'm using laravel 10.
I have following structure in DB
forum_categories
  id

forum_threads
  id
  forum_category_id

forum_posts
  id
  forum_thread_id

My goal is, using the eloquent get all categories with latest ForumPost model.
In model ForumCategory i have following method:
public function posts(): HasManyThrough
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough( ForumPost::class, ForumThread::class);
    }

And my query:
$categories =  ForumCategory::with(['posts' => function ($q) {
            $q->with('author')->latest();
        }])->get();

It works fine but it loads all ForumPosts not only the last one.
So, how to retrieve only the last one ForumPost for each category?
Thank you.

you can define another relationship hasOneThrough in your ForumCategory to fetch the latest post like,
public function latestPost()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(ForumPost::class, ForumThread::class)->latest('id');
}

and then,
$categories = ForumCategory::with('latestPost.author')->get();

